# Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, datetime

Mi problema es quiero agregar tres fechas que estan en formato de datetime en sql.

estas variables de fecha estan en un SP y al momento de enviar la informacion de forma manual en sql server:

```
exec spInsertaCargoCobranzaMV '00024','002',21554,1,0,500.00,'5-19-2017',1,-6,0,'12-12-2017','12-12-2018','SIMBANK','a3addaffedc7068e','20.6909728','-100.4432175'
```

Me sale el siguiente error

```
Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a datetime.
```

También intente ejecutar el sp de la siguiente forma:

```
exec spInsertaCargoCobranzaMV '00024','002',21554,1,0,500.00,'5/19/2017',1,-6,0,'12/12/2017','12/12/2018','SIMBANK','a3addaffedc7068e','20.6909728','-100.4432175'
```

Tambien de esta otra forma:

```
exec spInsertaCargoCobranzaMV '00024','002',21554,1,0,500.00,'5-19-2017 12:00:00 AM',1,-6,0,'12-12-2017 12:00:00 AM','12-12-2018 12:00:00 AM','SIMBANK','a3addaffedc7068e','20.6909728','-100.4432175'
```

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que el error proviene por el código que está en el *stored procedure* ya que SQL Server tiene la habilidad de *castear* una `VARCHAR` a `DATETIME` cuando es enviado como parámetro, por ejemplo, con algo como esto `EXEC spInsertaCargoCobranzaMV '00024','5-19-2017'` no deberías tener ningún problema ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas el formato `YYYYMMDD`, no deberías tener problemas donde la interpretación de la fecha depende de la configuración `DATEFORMAT`, `LANGUAGE`, etc.:

```
'20170519'
```

Para más información sobre los formatos de fecha que puedes usar de forma segura:

- [Usar datos de fecha y hora](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms180878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
- [What date/time literal formats are LANGUAGE and DATEFORMAT safe?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe)